# How can I view a sample flask application from github?

Tags: python

I am very confused about viewing a sample application on github with python/flask.

Here is my situation. I have followed all the instructions to develop a separate application with the official Flask documentation found here
[Flask Official Docs for Installation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/installation/#installation). I want to now incorporate bootstrap onto my application but before I do this I want to check out a sample repository found here [Github bootstrap-flask](https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/tree/master/sample_app). When I try to run `python frontend.py` I receive this error:

```
    File "frontend.py", line 8, in <module>
    from flask import Blueprint, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for
    ImportError: No module named flask
```

I don't understand how to fix this. I know that I have isolated my development application that I am working on in a virtual environment using venv. Am I supposed to do this with the bootstrap-flask github repo to view it? When I try to execute `virtualvenv application` or `pip install something` my system says I don't have the packages but I clearly do because I executed the easy_install instructions for both pip and virtualvenv on my Mac OSX. I don't understand the workflow. How does one view a flask application from Github?

Do you virtualvenv, git clone, and then pip install all the dependencies? Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need to execute `frontend.py` using the python under your virtualenv. So, the steps you would follow are:

1. `git clone https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap.git`
2. `cd flask-bootstrap/sample_application`
3. `virtualenv env`
4. `env/bin/pip install -r ./requirements.txt`
5. `env/bin/python frontend.py`

I hope this helps, please let me know how you get on, by leaving a comment.

Comment: Hey hd1, thanks for the comment and replying back. This definitely helped me along the only problem I am having is the last step. I get this error with executing env/bin/python frontend.py:

from .forms import SignupForm
  ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

I'm trying to make sense of it with this stackoverflow link and its references:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py

but if you happen to know what's wrong while I comb over the answer can you give me just one more boost to get going?

Comment: It looks like you may be missing a blank `__init__.py` in the directory.

Comment: Also, you might also want to accept the answer, if you found it helpful

Comment: Thanks hd1 for the help

Comment: No worries, @DanRubio

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're in the top level directory where your source code for the project is:

Create the virtualenv for your application. I named the environment `venv`:

`virtualenv venv`

Activate the virtualenv:

`source venv/bin/activate`

Install the requirements in the active virtualenv:

`pip install -r requiremements.txt`

Comment: (an earlier version of my answer had an error which was pointed out by @hd1 - thanks)